# Angular 2 bootsrap app component without template/template is served with html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular

I used to build applicaitons with angular1, there was possible to have directives on the allready loaded DOM elements, it was like you have the main component (app), wich is build from loaded html and then inside you can load directives from ether loaded html or load it from URL.

Howewer in angular2 it seems that to bootsrap application I have to use component which requires me to have template/templateURL, which I think is not nessesery since I don't want to load seperatly menues and other common stuff, I would rather do that on server level then laoding it seperatly. Does anyone knows how could I achive this in angular2?

Answer (score 3):

In Angular2 you need to bootstrap a component and a component needs to have a view. Directives can't be bootstrapped. Directives can't be added or removed dynamically, they are only applied where static HTML in a components view matches their selector.

To me it sounds that for your use case Angular1 is the better fit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what you are saying basicly is that in angular2 I have to run paralels requests to get my first body content.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how you conclude from my answer to "ave to run paralels requests". Can you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: Well with a first request I load whole page - javascript, meta etc but without <body> html. Then when bootsrtap kicks in I have to load <body> html(component loads it), in order to have directives and other components for every <body> html DOM. Please tell me that I'm wrong, and there is a way to solv it.

Comment: @mirazasx yes, that's right.  what you're looking for is transclusion, which isn't in angular2 the same way it is in angular1.  see https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Answer (score 2):

You can have directives but as @Günter Zöchbauer mentioned before you will need to bootstrap a component..

Change detector are created when a component is first instantiated. Here is an exaple for ng2 Directive from Angular documentation :

```
class Greeter {
   greet(name:string) {
     return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
   }
}
@Directive({
  selector: 'needs-greeter'
})
class NeedsGreeter {
  greeter:Greeter;
  constructor(greeter:Greeter) {
    this.greeter = greeter;
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'greet',
  viewProviders: [
    Greeter
  ],
  template: `<needs-greeter></needs-greeter>`,
  directives: [NeedsGreeter]
})
class HelloWorld {
}
```

See for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html#!#constructor

But keep in mind that:

> Each Angular component requires a single @Component annotation. The
>   @Component annotation specifies when a component is instantiated, and
>   which properties and hostListeners it binds to.
>
> When a component is instantiated, Angular
>
> - creates a shadow DOM for the component.
> - loads the selected template into the shadow DOM.
> - creates all the injectable objects configured with providers and viewProviders.

Comment: Well, my problem is that I don't want to load whole body HTML via component's templateUrl, I would prefer to have it loaded with initial page request and then take over with javascript. That I managed to do with angular1. The user has a spare milisecond to think what to click while I'm initiating angular. Btw thanks for example, it's definatly usefull now in the begining.